# need help in English grammar

Tags: grammar

Do you think this might help you?

my answer : **yes defiantly this might help me**

is my answer above correct ?

Comment: *Might* indicates at least some possibility that it will not help. *Definitely* does not fit easily with that, however grammatical it may be. *Defiantly* is, um, something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word you are looking for is 'definitely'.

> in a definite way : in a way free of all ambiguity, uncertainty, or obscurity

[Full definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/definitely)